# php preg_match expression to detect valid facebook post and video urls

Tags: php, regex, facebook

How can I detect if a) the link is valid (structurally) and b) if it is a valid facebook photo or video link? Looking for the regular expressions for each case, not to determine if it's accessible or a valid destination.

Example photo link:
https://www.facebook.com/949pediatricdentistry/photos/a.1438335623065047.1073741827.1438300469735229/1866032310295374/?type=3&theater

Example video link:
https://www.facebook.com/chevrolet/videos/10153947517247296/

I've tried the following preg_match() statement which is close to detecting the different photo urls, but not fully passing the test:

```
preg_match('^(http(?:s?)?://www\.facebook\.com/(?:photo\.php\?fbid=\d+|([A-z0-9\.]+)\/photos(?:\/[0-9A-z].+)?\/(\d+)(?:.+)))?', 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10201485039580806&set=a.2923144830611.2133032.1020548245&type=3&theater');

preg_match('^(http(?:s?)?://www\.facebook\.com/(?:photo\.php\?fbid=\d+|([A-z0-9\.]+)\/photos(?:\/[0-9A-z].+)?\/(\d+)(?:.+)))?', 'https://www.facebook.com/949pediatricdentistry/photos/a.1438335623065047.1073741827.1438300469735229/1866032310295374/?type=3&theater');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: I'm not looking for a free code writing service. I struggle with regular expressions and this is a complex problem. I am surprised that there are not more solutions online so I think my question holds some value. Searching for a correct solution for this comes up rather bare. I've updated my question to show the preg_match() statements I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the host + facebook account + video/photo routine:

```
<?php
    $link = 'https://www.facebook.com/949pediatricdentistry/photos/a.1438335623065047.1073741827.1438300469735229/1866032310295374/?type=3&theater';
    $faceLink = explode('/', $link);
    if (($faceLink[2] == 'www.facebook.com' && $faceLink[3] == $username)) {
   //IS VALID
           if ($faceLink[4] == 'photos') {
             //photos routine
             } else if ($faceLink[4] == 'videos') {
               //videos routine
           }
    }
?>
```

Try by yourself before ask into Stack.

Comment: Thank you, this I could have done, however, a preg_match() statement would be best when the link is embedded with other text.

Comment: Not exactly. With you have links with a simple pattern, rely on preg_match it's a shotgun to kill a fly. If you could have done this, why didn't told in you question about the limit wanted by your algorithm?

Whatever, it's ok, you're welcome.

Comment: Thank you, I did write "Looking for the regular expressions for each case".